# Sending account details to user after account is confirmed

Tags: php

This is my Activation Email so Far,but i want details to email to user after email is confirmed.the email confirmation works fine,but i want to send account details to users after email is confirmed.

```
if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email']))
{
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))//The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}


if (isset($email) && isset($key))
{

    // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

    $query_activate_account = "UPDATE members SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1";


    $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account) ;

    // Print a customized message:
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)//if update query was successfull
    {
    echo '<div class="success">Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';

    } else
    {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Oops! Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link if its expired or you activated before. contact us via contact@xxxxx.com</div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

} else {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Error Occured .</div>';
}


?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thank you so much JammyDodger231,its been fixed and working now.
here's what finally did it.

<?php

include ('database_connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email']))
{
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))//The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}


if (isset($email) && isset($key))
{

    // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

    $query_activate_account = "UPDATE members SET Activation=NULL WHERE(email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1";


    $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account) ;

    // Print a customized message:
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)//if update query was successfull
    {

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email ='$email'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


                $headers .= "BCC: xxxxxx@yahoo.com\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: My Site <no-reply@xxxxx.com>' . "\r\n";

                $message = " Your Account has now been verified, Below are your Details.\n\n";
                $message .= "

                username: ".$row['username']."
                Password: ".$row['Password']." 
                Account Number: ".$row['randomnumber']."

                Please Ensure you keep safely.\n";
        }       

    echo '<div class="success">Your account is now active and your Account details sent to you. 

You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';
    mail ($email, "Activation Success",  $message, $headers); 
  } else
    {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Oops! Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link if its expired or you activated before.</div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

} else {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Error Occured .</div>';
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you not just need to send mail here:

```
// Print a customized message:
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)//if update query was successfull
{
    echo '<div class="success">Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';
    mail ($email, "Activation Success", $body, $from)

}
```

The mail parameters will be selected from your data like which are the things you want in the `$body`.

Comment: The mail parameters were not select from the Database,now i get account activation email,but username and Password comes blank

Comment: Where does it come blank?

Comment: it comes blank in the received email

Comment: What did you put the text you want to be sent in the email in the `$body` variable? If not what have you tried?

Comment: $message = " Your Account has now been verified, Below are your Details.\n\n";
    $message .= "
    
    Username: $username
    Password: $Password
    Serial Number: $randomnumber
    
    Please Ensure you keep safely.";

Comment: i tried using the $email to fetch the $username , $Password and $randomnumber from the database so i can email to user in that the activation page

Comment: if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email']))
{
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))//The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}
if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];
}
if(isset($_GET['Password'])) {
    $Password = $_GET['Password'];
}
if(isset($_GET['randomnumber'])) {
    $randomnumber = $_GET['randomnumber'];
}

if (isset($email) && isset($key))

Comment: So this is what you have? `// Print a customized message:
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)//if update query was successful
{

    $body= " Your Account has now been verified, Below are your Details.\n\n"; $message .= " Username: $username Password: $Password Serial Number: $randomnumber Please Ensure you keep safely.";
    mail ($email, "Activation Success", $body, $from)

}`